# PySide2 not updating QLabel text when asked

Tags: python-3.6, macos-high-sierra, pyside2

I am upgrading from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6 and from PySide to PySide2. I started by trying to get the "Hello World" from the "Getting Started" site (https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/gettingstarted.html) working. It displays the widget, its label and the push button, but the push button does not change the text of the label. I added a print() to verify that the button is indeed calling the method associated with the click signal, and even added an update() to try to "encourage" it a bit more. No luck.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Copied from:
#   https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython/gettingstarted.html
#
# Mac OS X High Sierra (10.13.6)
#
# Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 05:52:31) 
# [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
#
# PySide2 5.11.1 
#

import sys
import random
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.hello = ["Hallo Welt", "你好，世界", "Hei maailma",
                      "Hola Mundo", "Привет мир"]

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me!")
        self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World")
        self.text.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.text.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Titillium", 30))
        self.button.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Titillium", 20))

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.magic)

    def magic(self):
        hi = random.choice(self.hello)
        print(hi)              # Prints when clicked
        self.text.setText(hi)  # Label text does not change when clicked
#       self.update()          # Didn't help

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(800, 600)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Installed with pipenv. And, the Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[[source]]
url = "http://download.qt.io/snapshots/ci/pyside/5.11/latest"
verify_ssl = false
name = "qt5"

[packages]
pyside2 = {version="*", index="qt5"}

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Comment: I also tried eliminating the setFont calls and simply setting the text to "Clicked" instead of a random string. Again, it printed "Clicked" to the terminal window but did not change the QLabel.

Comment: have tried it in Arch Linux and it works correctly, most likely the problem is caused by the way you have installed, so it is advisable to explain your installation process

Comment: @eyllanesc It works fine in my Arch Linux system as well. In both cases I used pipenv. (On both systems, I even backed it down to Python 2.7, and again Arch worked, Mac OS X did not.)

Comment: It smells like a bug, lately I've seen many similar posts, so if it works in one OS and not in another implies that the code is correct and the problem is PySide2, and that will be difficult to correct here, reports the bug.

Comment: Same issue with my Mac. Is there a way to force update of the window? If you adjust side of the window the correct new random message shows.

Comment: See [PYSIDE-695](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-695) and [PYSIDE-871](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-871).

Answer (score 7):

Fixed this problem on my Mac under python3.6 by adjusting the magic function:

```
def magic(self):
    self.text.setText(random.choice(self.hello))
    self.repaint()
```

The self.repaint() is needed for some reason, but at least works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PySide2==5.15.0 then you need to upgrade it to 5.15.1 and thats what solved my problem.

Command to upgrade PySide2:

```
pip/pip3 install --upgrade PySide2
```